# LINQ nested query issue - System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to reproduce the following SQL query in LINQ:

```
select *
  from dbo.events_log 
 where std_datetimeseq < '2014011523:49:00001'
   and logname in ('S', 'D', 'O')
   and std_datetimeseq = (
       select min(std_datetimeseq)
         from dbo.events_log
        where std_datetimeseq < '2014011523:49:00001'
          and logname in ('S', 'D', 'O'))
```

This is what I have:

```
from e in _context.EventLogs
                    where e.std_datetimeseq.CompareTo(stdDateTimeSeq) < 0
                      && eventMessage.Content.EquipToSearch.Contains(e.logname)
                      && e.std_datetimeseq.CompareTo(
                      ((from e2 in _context.EventLogs
                        where e2.std_datetimeseq.CompareTo(stdDateTimeSeq) < 0
                            && eventMessage.Content.EquipToSearch.Contains(e2.logname)
                        select e2).Min().std_datetimeseq)) == 0
                           select e
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
{"The specified method 'MyEntityModel.EventLog Min[EventLog](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[HDSREntityDataModelNS.EventLog])' 
on the type 'System.Linq.Queryable' cannot be translated into 
a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments."}
```

I have no idea what's wrong.

eventMessage.Content.EquipToSearch is a List with "S", "D", "O" in it. The LINQ is going against entity framework.

Thanks

Comment: First try changing `select e2).Min().std_datetimeseq)) == 0` to `select e2.std_datetimeseq).Min())) == 0`.

Comment: Rather than using `CompareTo` to compare the dates, just use the less than and equality operators.

Comment: Also, as a general rule whenever you have an error like this, try cutting pieces of the query bit by bit to try to find the smallest query that still produces the error; rather than just trying to guess at what's broken, and thus what needs to be re-written.

Comment: It was as easy as changing select e2).Min().std_datetimeseq)) == 0 to e2.std_datetimeseq).Min())) == 0. Thanks for both of your suggestions.

Comment: @juharr You should post that as the answer; apparently that was the only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the sub query

```
(from e2 in _context.EventLogs
 where e2.std_datetimeseq.CompareTo(stdDateTimeSeq) < 0
    && eventMessage.Content.EquipToSearch.Contains(e2.logname)
 select e2).Min().std_datetimeseq
```

In order to get the min `std_datetimeseq` value you have to select it, otherwise you are trying to find the minimum `EventLogs` item which not only doesn't make sense, but cannot be translated to SQL by EF.  Instead do the following.

```
(from e2 in _context.EventLogs
 where e2.std_datetimeseq < stdDateTimeSeq
    && eventMessage.Content.EquipToSearch.Contains(e2.logname)
 select e2.std_datetimese).Min()
```

On a side note your query will be easier to read if you just use the comparison operators instead of `CompareTo` as suggested by Servy.